# How to click on a single element until the element is not visible at all in robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I need to click on an element until the element is not visible, it goes of after clicking 30 times at max. So I've been trying out an for loop for this process. But I am completely new to Robot framework so I need some help. Here's my code from which I've been trying.

```
 ${BUTTON} =    run keyword and return status    element should be visible     ${NextButton}
    FOR    ${BUTTON}    IN RANGE    30
        IF    ${BUTTON} == ${True}    click element    ${NextButton}
        sleep    2s
        ${BUTTON} =    run keyword and return status    element should be visible    ..${NextButton}
        EXIT FOR LOOP IF    ${BUTTON} == ${False}
    END
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable for the loop:

```
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    30
```

Otherwise, you're constantly reassigning `${BUTTON}` to a number, and it's losing its boolean value.

---

By the way, inside the loop the locator is prefixed with two dots - `..${NextButton` - I don't know is that intentional, but doesn't look so.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, I cracked the way to make it work, here is what i tried 


${BUTTON} =    run keyword and return status   

 element should be visible    ${ReaderNextButton}
    WHILE   ${BUTTON}
        click element    ${ReaderNextButton}
        sleep    0.5s
        ${BUTTON} =    run keyword and return status    element should be visible    ${ReaderNextButton}
    END

Comment: That's a way, but think what will happen if the button never becomes visible :) Hint - you have to add a break out condition, at some time.

Answer (score 0):

I cracked the way to make it work, here is what i tried ${BUTTON} = run keyword and return status element should be visible

```
${BUTTON} =    run keyword and return status    element should be visible    ${ReaderNextButton}
    WHILE   ${BUTTON}
        click element    ${ReaderNextButton}
        sleep    0.5s
        ${BUTTON} =    run keyword and return status    element should be visible    ${ReaderNextButton}
    END
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
 wait until keyword succeeds          35x      0s         run keyword    Click nextbutton if visible         
        
    
Click nextbutton if visible
     ${BUTTON}=          Run Keyword And Return Status       run keyword     wait until element is visible      ${NextButton}         10s
      Run Keyword If      '${result}'=='True'                 click element    ${NextButton}
      wait until element is not visible  ${NextButton}         10s
```